# Bitwise check if some flags are set, others aren't?

Tags: objective-c, bit-manipulation, flags

I have a int-flag which will be like this:

- 0 = unseen, unread
- 1 = Seen
- 2 = Read
- 4 = answered

Now I have this code:

```
if (flag & 4) //Beantwortet
{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"beantwortet-40.png"];
}
else  if (flag & 2) //ungelesen
{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Flag1-40.png"]; 
    
}
else
{
       imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"neu-40.png"];
}
```

Which means first if: answered, second if: readed, last if: unreaded.

Now a user can be answered a mail, but set the flag manually to unread. That means the int value is 5.

How to check this?

I tried this:

```
else if (flag & 4 && flag & 1) //Beantwortet, aber auf "Nicht gelesen" gesetzt
{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"neu-40.png"];
}
```

But I not only get 5 in this, I get 7 also.
How to check for 5, but not for 7?

Comment: as an aside, you should probably make the "answered and unread" check first, since if such a message comes through, your `if(flag & 4)` check is going to fire first.

Comment: Alternatively, you could make the first case nested, so it checks for 4; if true, it checks for (1 && !2). Depending on whether that's true, you set either beantwortet-40.png or neu-40.png.

Comment: The nested thing worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious would be `if((flag & 5) && !(flag & 2))`

Comment: you can of course say `if((flag & 4) && (flag & 1) && !(flag & 2))` if you want to keep the flags separate.

Comment: Tried it, but I don't know why, but the 5 nor the 7 get catched

Answer (score 1):

Why not just check to see if the int value is 5, like you say?

```
else if (flag == 5) //Beantwortet, aber auf "Nicht gelesen" gesetzt
{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"neu-40.png"];
}
```

**Update** : If you have more flags beyond the first four, you can pre-filter the value and then do the check:

```
else if ((flag & 7) == 5) //Beantwortet, aber auf "Nicht gelesen" gesetzt
{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"neu-40.png"];
}
```

That will mask out all the flags except for the first three, so even if others are set at e.g., 8 or 16, they will not play a part in this check.

Comment: Because it's open end... There is a 8 and a 16 and a 32, so ==5 would be a int-like operator not a bitwise operator

Comment: So there are more flags than the ones you mention in the question? That changes things somewhat, but you can still pre-filter the value.